# Manipulate the process which executes the application

Tags: windows, process

I recently digging into Windows with "Windows Internal" and "Windows via C/C++" and makes me think about manipulate the process while reading about process and its kernal related object.

What book says there are variety options you can use for process creation like security attribute, handle inheritance, size, initial position and title of window and so on. However, it can be applicable when you explicitly create a process with function call 'CreateProcess' if I'm right. A process creation is an unusual work and I believe most of situations can be covered with thread creation or Task creation from C#.

So, my question is, I have a program to print out the "Hello World." on console screen and and want to manipulate the process which execute my code. Obviously there are no CreateProcess function call but process must be created to execute my program with its main thread.

1. Does process which runs my code is created by Window?
2. If possible, How to manipulate the process which automatically(?) created to execute my code?

I really appreciate any helps, comments and links. (And please understand my  english. Not native speaker.)

**Update**

Based on the comment from eryksun (Thank you!), When I create a program based on CUI (or GUI either), shell will makes a process to execute my program. From the book, we can deliver `STARTUPINFO` which has an initial configuration about title, position, size (and so on...) of window to `[createprocess][1]` function call.

Question: I want to set size and position of initial window for console window with print out the "Hello world". If shell makes for me, How to configure the initial value for it?

Another question: From the book "Windows Internal", it says you can create a process without any thread which is meaningless and not useful but sill possible. How?

Comment: You're likely running from either a GUI shell (Explorer) or a console shell (CMD, PowerShell). The shell is what executes the program by calling `CreateProcess`. What do you mean by "manipulate" the process? Keep the question focused on something specific you need to understand or accomplish.

Comment: With CMD's `start` and PowerShell's `start-process`, you can set the initial window state (minimized, maximized) -- but not the console window size and position.

Comment: That said, console properties can be set in a subkey for a given window title, e.g. "HKCU\Console\<window title>". CMD's `start` command allows setting the initial title of a new window, and reg.exe can add the window-title subkey. Set DWORD values for WindowPosition (two 16-bit values packed as Top & Left in screen coordinates) and WindowSize (two 16-bit values packed as Height, Width in characters, e.g. 0x00190050 sets the height as 0x0050 == 80 and width as 0x0019 == 25).

Comment: I see no point in the follow-up question about creating a process without a thread. It's not related to setting `STARTUPINFO` information for a process run from a shell. It would involve calling `NtCreateProcess` directly, which is outside of the scope of Windows API programming.